# How to filter by multiple select options in backbone

Tags: backbone.js

Currently what I have is *almost* working. I'm using the following:

```
this.collection.reset(jobArray, {silent: true});

var filterDepartment = this.filterDepartment;
var filterCategory = this.filterCategory;
var filterLocation = this.filterLocation;

var filteredResult = this.collection.where({
    department: filterDepartment,
    category: filterCategory,
    location: filterLocation
 });

 this.collection.reset(filteredResult);
```

This works great if I select a department, a category, and a location. However, if I want it to only filter by department + location, leaving category as the default 'all' value, it should return the filtered/ selected department and location, within all categories. Furthermore, if I select a category, then select "all" instead, it should then only be searching by location.

I have a way to do this but it is a LOT of code, surely there is an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
this.collection.reset(jobArray, {silent: true});

var filterDepartment = this.filterDepartment;
var filterCategory = this.filterCategory;
var filterLocation = this.filterLocation;

var filter = {};
if (filterDepartment)
    filter['department'] = filterDepartment

if (filterCategory)
    filter['category'] = filterCategory;

if (filterLocation)
    filter['location'] = filterLocation;

console.log(filter); // Dump the filter

var filteredResult = this.collection.where(filter);

this.collection.reset(filteredResult);
```

Comment: That is mostly working, thanks! The only issue now is that once I've selected an option, then select the default 'all' option everything is hidden. I've tried changing your code to something like:

   if ((filterDepartment) && (filterDepartment != 'all'))

Comment: `if (filterDepartment && filterDepartment != 'all')` sounds correct for me. Are u sure it's `all` (not `All` or `ALL`)? Also try to dump the filter after it's assigned, and see if it's correct (updated question).

Comment: It was working, but I had to wrap the entire thing in a conditional statement. Thanks for your help! [Here is the final code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27283544/965940)

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by using [Khang Nguen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27282868/965940) code and adding a conditional statement, the final code is as follows:

```
if ((!this.filterDepartment) && (!this.filterCategory) && (!this.filterLocation)) {
    this.collection.reset(jobArray);
} else {
   this.collection.reset(jobArray, {silent: true});

   var filterDepartment = this.filterDepartment;
   var filterCategory = this.filterCategory;
   var filterLocation = this.filterLocation;

   var filter = {};
   if (filterDepartment) {
       filter['department'] = filterDepartment;
   }

   if (filterCategory) {
       filter['category'] = filterCategory;
   }

   if (filterLocation) {
       filter['location'] = filterLocation;
   }

   var filteredResult = this.collection.where(filter);

   this.collection.reset(filteredResult);
}
```

Also removed the "all" value from the default select options.